# azure functions running in sequence, parallel desired

Tags: c#, azure, parallel-processing, azure-functions

I have an azure function that I'm calling in parallel using postasync...

I arrange all my tasks in a queue and then wait for the responses in parallel using "WhenAll".

I can confirm that there is a burst of HTTP activity out to Azure and then HTTP activity stops on my local machine while I wait for responses from Azure.

When I monitor the function in Azure Portal, it looks like the requests are arriving every three seconds or so, even though from my side there is no network traffic after the initial burst.

When I get my results back, they are arriving in sequence, in the exact same order I sent them out, even though the Azure Portal monitor indicates that some functions take 10 seconds to run and some take 3 seconds to run.

I am using Azure functions Version 1 with a consumption service plan.

```
CentralUSPlan (Consumption: 0 Small)
```

My host.json file is empty ==> {}

Why is this happening?  Is there some setting that is required to get azure functions to execute in parallel?

```
public async Task<List<MyAnalysisObject>> DoMyAnalysisObjectsHttpRequestsAsync(List<MyAnalysisObject> myAnalysisObjectList)
{
    List<MyAnalysisObject> evaluatedObjects = new List<MyAnalysisObject>();

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task<MyAnalysisObject>>();

        foreach (var myAnalysisObject in myAnalysisObjectList)
        {
            tasks.Add(DoMyAnalysisObjectHttpRequestAsync(client, myAnalysisObject));
        }

        var evaluatedObjectsArray = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        evaluatedObjects.AddRange(evaluatedObjectsArray);
    }

    return evaluatedObjects;
}

public async Task<MyAnalysisObject> DoMyAnalysisObjectHttpRequestAsync(HttpClient client, MyAnalysisObject myAnalysisObject)
{
    string requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myAnalysisObject);

    Console.WriteLine("Doing post-async:" + myAnalysisObject.Identifier);

    var response = await client.PostAsync(
                    "https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/BuildMyAnalysisObject?code=XXX",
                    new StringContent(requestJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                    );

    Console.WriteLine("Finished post-async:" + myAnalysisObject.Identifier);

    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Console.WriteLine("Got result:" + myAnalysisObject.Identifier);

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyAnalysisObject>(result);
}
```

Comment: So you are saying the output of `DoMyAnalysisObjectHttpRequestAsync` shows several blocks of 3 lines in the order of "doing post-async", "Finished posrt-async", "Got result"? 


Can you post the console output?

Comment: You probably want to say that HttpClient doesn't do requests in parallel? Which it's strange, but maybe you hit the [connection limit](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Managing-Connections).

Comment: I guess the problem is that azure functions don't scale well when when there are longer workhorse functions that come at intermittent times:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1206

Comment: My guess is this [Sec 8.1.2.2 Pipelining](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) says: "A server MUST send its responses to requests in the same order that the requests were received".